# SSO implementation using php

Tags: php, ldap, single-sign-on, saml

I have some open source application resides on my server as well as some other application.

Like open project, matter most, own cloud etc and i have to implement single sign on functionality for all of those application.

but don't know from where to start or how to proceed further. And my networking concept are really too weak.

I searched for LDAP client server,SAML but did not get relevant way to accomplish the task(Or the step wise process)

and wants to implement the system in laravel(PHP)

Please help me out to solve these challenging task.

Comment: Are you looking for SingleSigbOn or One Password For All? Do you have any existing Login-Solutions (like LDAP, Kerberos, OAuth or SAML) that can or shall be used?

Answer (score 1):

The best SSO solution for PHP is [simpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/).

There's a lot of documentation there that will answer most of your questions.

Comment: "Best" is highly subjective.  I prefer Barebones SSO Server/Client (http://barebonescms.com/documentation/sso/).  Full disclosure:  I'm the author.  Ease of understanding code structure and number of security vulnerabilities in a product should also play a part in deciding what solution to use.  SimpleSAML follows PSRs, which results in files everywhere on the file system.  Barebones SSO has had zero vulnerabilities in the last year while SimpleSAML has seen 6 distinct vulnerabilities.  Different solutions to the same problem - neither one is necessarily best.

Comment: Interesting - one I hadn't heard off. A quick scan through the doco. and I can't see any reference to the protocol - is it SAML? or any federation. Does it work with ADFS / Azure AD / shibboleth? Does it follow the normal metadata exchange?

Comment: Server session initiation utilizes a custom protocol.  The server and client software knows how to talk to the other - users shouldn't have to care what protocol is in use as long as it works.  A custom protocol was necessary to be able to optionally pick up and restore right where the user left off mid-request without requiring PHP session support (e.g. user submits a form but the user's session timed out).  The SSO server supports AD via the included LDAP Provider.